# "findOne()" equivalent to add to MEANjs user profile with articles list functionality

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, crud

Building on the self-answer to this excellent question: [MEANJS user profile functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631006/meanjs-user-profile-functionality).  They wanted to add the functionality to the meanjs scaffold that you can navigate to any user's page and you'll get essentially a profile page with a list of all of their posts.  It seems to work fine.

I wanted to add a "findOne()" equivalent method here - so that for each article/post that's listed, if we click on it, we'll have more options specific to the retrieved information about each article.

However, and maybe it is a simple mental block I've created myself because I'm so inexperienced, I can't really think of how to implement this in their structure.

For example, see their code:

"I added this line to posts.server.routes.js:

```
app.route('/api/posts/of/:userid').get(posts.listOf);
```

... and this part to posts.server.controller.js:

```
exports.listOf = function(req, res) { Post.find( { user: req.params.userid }).sort('-created').exec(function(err, posts) {
if (err) {
    return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    });
} else {
    res.jsonp(posts);
}
});
};
```

So - would I put a findOne method here, since listOf is essentially a "find" method?  The thing is - the routing and routeparams/stateparams becomes unclear to me then.  IE - is the applicable server route now `/api/posts/of/:userid/:postid`?  And then the method query uses `{ user: req.params.userid }, { post = req.params.postid }`?  That makes sense conceptually, but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use multiple routeParams in that way.  And if I'm not mistaken - this only covers creating the restful endpoints, right?

For client side, from their SO question/answer:

"Open users.client.routes.js and add this:

```
state('users', {
            url: '/users/:username',
            templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/view-profile.client.view.html'
        });
```

Template Url points to newly created html file which I want to use for user profile page. So create this file under client/views folder:

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-ng-controller="ViewProfileController" data-ng-init="findUser()">
...
{{ ourUser }}
<hr />
{{ userPosts }}
....
```

You can fill this file as you like. I created a new controller for this view. As you can see its name is ViewProfileController. And I have a findUser function to do the job. Here is the controller code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('users').controller('ViewProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'Users', 'Authentication', '$stateParams', 
function($scope, $http, $location, Users, Authentication, $stateParams) {
    $scope.user = Authentication.user;

    $scope.findUser = function () {

       $scope.ourUser = Users.get({
            username: $stateParams.username
        }).$promise.then( function(ourUser) {
               var userPostsPromise = $http.get('api/posts/of/' + ourUser._id);
               userPostsPromise.success(function(data) {
                   $scope.userPosts=data;
                   $scope.ourUser=ourUser;
               });
               userPostsPromise.error(function() {
                   alert('Something wrong!');
               });
           }
       );
    };

}
]);
```

(end of content cited from their post)

I think I understand this controller function "findUser": find the username associated with the url request, then find their posts based on an http GET request to the RESTful endpoint created above, @ the `'api/posts/of' + username._id`.  But, again, how do we add findOne() to this?  This seems like where a more simple solution fits - but I don't know how to integrate their solution with what I would do normally for a client-side findOne():

articles.client.controller.js:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    $scope.article = Articles.get({
        articleId: $routeParams.articleId
});
```

(Or I guess $stateParams since the SO answer I linked uses ui-router).

And the Articles service client-side would be:

articles.client.service.js:

```
angular.module('articles').factory('Articles', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('api/articles/:articleId', {
    articleId: '@_id'
  }, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
}]);
```

For my `$scope.article`, could I .get by article ID referenced in the list of articles in the view (a la the other poster's solution) and ignore the user/posts routing structure when you go to findOne()?  So I would use their structure for the ._id of a post, and then when the user clicks on it for more detailed options, it routes client-side to `api/posts/:postid` (no user)?  Still not sure how to do that, or if it's stupid and I should stick with `api/:user/posts/:postid` or (`api/:user/:postid`)?  How do I use multiple routeparams here (note that that's only a part of the question)?

Edit: Or should it be static methods, like:

```
UserSchema.statics.findOneByUsername = function (username, callback) {
  this.findOne({ username: new RegExp(username, 'i') }, callback);
};
```

Now Im even more confused.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get a working solution to this? I cant even get the list of posts working as it throws an error with the  $http.get('api/posts/of/' + ourUser._id); saying that it expects an object but gets an array.